# Iptables on centos 7 rejects SSH and WHM connection

Tags: ssh, cpanel, centos7, iptables

I installed centos 7 and cPanel; disabled/masked firewalld and installed and enabled iptables. As soon as I enabled iptables, I disconnected from WHM and SSH. When I disable iptables in rescue mode, I can connect to server via SSH and WHM. 
I checked the rules in /etc/sysconfig/iptables, but there is no any rule that rejects access to SSH or WHM ports. 
My next step was to install CSF.
Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The quick solution to get rid of the issue is flushing all the Iptables rules with the command

iptables -F

However since you want to keep the Iptables running you will have to configure it to open the required ports with the command

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT  --- 22 is for SSH , same way you will have to open other ports.